# Best performance to loop 2 million records and generate a set of updates or inserts depending on certain condition in each row

Tags: sql, database, ssis, database-migration

I'm currently using SSIS 2012 for a large data migration exercise.

I have a task to complete but not sure best approach.

Table A has 2.1million records.

I need to iterate each row and:

Step 1. Update a specific field with results from a complex subquery doing some text manipulation

Step 2. grab an email address from email field in TableA row
2a. look up user table
2b. if email exists get ID and update UserId in TableA row
2c. if email doesn't exists - INSERT new record into User table, get ID back and update UserId in TableA row

Step 1 and 2 don't have to be done at the same time, these tasks can be split into separate Data Flows as they are unrelated.

I can write this all using a cursor - pretty straightforward, but I know as a general rule using cursors is frowned upon.

I have written a pure sql script for Step 1 above, using the new MERGE function. The sub query it uses calls a View which in turn uses a scaler function to do some complex text manipulation. After this ran via SSIS for 1h 12m SSIS bombed out due to tembDB.log running out of disk space.

Not sure if my query was the cause of tembDB getting out of control or something else in the SSIS package which ran earlier? How can I tell?

So has anyone got any tips on best tools within SSIS to achieve both Step 1 and 2 above?

Comment: I think you need to show data and what update (Query) you try to run 1 Step.

Comment: An important thing to do when doing big MERGE statements, is to check if the column you are modifying has an index on it. If it does, update/insert is going to be slow. Drop the index on the column, run MERGE, and then re-create the index.

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering what constrains you to use SSIS rather than raw SQL.  Is this a one-off job, rather than a regular data-feed?  If it's one-off, I'd be tempted to pull the source data into a staging table in the destination DB (or a separate staging DB on same server), and do the complex stuff there.  SSIS is great for repeated, regular data-feeds; if this isn't required, then I'd go with SQL.

(TBH I haven't explored some of SSIS's more advanced features, row-level operations).

You could split Step 2 into two SQL statements, operating on separate sets:

**a.** Set of rows where email DOES exist;

**b.** Set of rows where email DOESN'T exist

making the "triage" of rows before you even start, rather than on each individual row; with some careful checks that your two sets are covering the entire table.  You could do this in separate data flows in SSIS if you prefer SSIS (as long as your source DB allows you to run SQL against it, rather than just getting the entire table dumped in).

Answer (score 0):

For Step 1, the SSIS equivalent of "a complex subquery" is usually a Data Flow with Lookup(s).  The SSIS equivalent of "text manipulation" / "scalar function" is usually a Data Flow with a Script Transformation. Whatever manipulation you can code in T-SQL can be done in .NET, you can leverage the .NET library e.g. Regex, HTMLEncode etc and it will likely be more elegant and run faster.

For Step 2, I would start a new Data Flow with an OLE DB Source that gives you the distinct email values from TableA.  Then add a Lookup transformation to check against your "user table". Ignore matches and send unmatched rows to an OLE DB Destination to insert them into your "user table".

Then add another Data Flow that takes all the TableA rows, lookups up the "user table" values and inserts the lot to a staging table. If you must get everything back into TableA you can then truncate and reload it at this point - much faster than an update or cursor.